# Question on the distribution of eigenvalues in a square matrix with random entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Let square matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$, have entries that have been independently sampled from a uniform distribution between $[a_1,a_2]$. The symmetric part of $A$, $A_s$ is defined as $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$.

The question I have is what distribution will the eigenvalues of the symmetric part $A_s$ fall under?

**My Approach:** My exploration began by looking at the characteristic polynomial of $A_s$

$$P_A(t) = det(tI - A_s)$$

The roots of the characteristic polynomial will be the eigenvalues of the $A_s$. By Leibniz's formula the determinant will be equal to: 
$$det(M) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}{sgn(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^{n}{m_{i,\sigma_i}}}$$
Where the sum is computed over all the permutations of $\{1,2,3,...n\}$, and $sgn$ is the parity of the permutation.

My intuition from looking at Leibniz's formula tells me that the eigenvalues should also be distributed uniformly bounded by new constants. But I have not found a way to show this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at the paper by Wigner in the Annals of Math,  vol 67, no 2 (March 1958), p 325 (which points to other earlier work) for some information on this question when the matrices are symmetric. It gives a pretty decent answer in this case (for large $n$).

Comment: I rephrased my question to work on a symmetric matrix to insure that the eigenvalues will be real. Thanks for the paper. Was very helpful.

Comment: You can find a summary of this result (Wigner's Semicircle Law) in [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html).

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I had no idea it had a name -- I just happened to have read that issue of the Annals. :)